# Scala Nil equivalent for Set

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there an equivalent of `Nil` for `Set` in scala?

I tried using `Nil` as a value for `Set`, but I got an error (expected since the type of `Nil` is `List`)

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Set.empty` is that set; although you can't get at it directly, it turns out that it is just a private object in the `Set` companion object (called, obviously enough, `EmptySet`).  All that `Set.empty` does is return that set with a cast to the correct type.

It is done this way, instead of with `Nil`, because sets are *invariant* in their parameters.  `Nil` is `List[Nothing]()`, but you couldn't add anything to a `Set[Nothing]()`.

If you need to specify the type of your empty set, you can use e.g. `Set.empty[String]`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Set.empty` or simply `Set()`.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for `Set.empty`